# Usage and order of "galore": an adjective, but looks like an adverb

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, syntactic-analysis, postpositive

It is common to put adverbs of manner after a direct object. But is it grammatically correct to put an *adjective* after noun? As in:

1. Since then there have been reports, inquiries and guidance **galore**.

Why can't it be like this, if it's an adjective modifying a noun:

1. Since then there have been **galore** reports, inquiries and guidance.

Also, I am not sure whether this is a postpositive adjective or a reduced phrase adjective.

I have Googled and but couldn't get the actual answer of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***[Galore](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/galore)***  is an interesting word, an example of [postpositive adjective](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postpositive_adjective).

Usage:

> ***The Irish phrase go lear literally translates as “to sufficiency.***” If there are sufficient enough bananas to build a house with them, you’d say that there are bananas galore.
>
> ***The word is an example of a postpositive adjective, which means it comes after the word it describes.*** So when you go to a circus and 700 clowns surround you, don’t say “There are galore clowns,” because the correct way to express your terror is this: “There are clowns galore. Help!”

(Vocabulary.com)

Comment: Your answer seems helpful... I have another question; can we call it as reduced phrase?

Comment: @IqbalAhmedSiyal It's just a single word adjective, that comes after the noun. It's not a 'reduced phrase'

Comment: It can't be a reduced phrase because _galore_ can't be used as a predicate adjective; in particular, it can't be the predicate adjective of a putative *_guidance which was  galore_ that might reduce to _guidance galore_. _Galore_ is a stock example of the individual peculiarities of individual lexical items in English or any other language.

Comment: 'Galore' can equally be considered a quantifier. In fact, I'd paraphrase 'There were pavilions galore' as 'There were many gay pavilions'.